# Adding thousand separator to jQuery Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

I am trying to add commas (thousand separator) for big numbers that use the follow counter function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.Count').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            jQuery({Counter: 0}).animate({Counter: $this.text()}, {
                duration: 1500,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function() {
                    $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Do I modify this particular formula or do I have to write an additional function that will handle the formatting?

Comment: so what's the problem that you want to get solved?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to have my counter animation run on large numbers that use that use commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might work

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.Count').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        jQuery({Counter: 0}).animate({Counter: $this.text()}, {
            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function() {
                var num = Math.ceil(this.Counter).toString();
                if(Number(num) > 999){
                    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(num)) {
                        num = num.replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
                    }
                }
                $this.text(num);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Maybe you can help me sort out another issue. I have large and small numbers using the animation. Small numbers away finish on the right number but the larger numbers almost always off by a few points. Any idea as to why that is happening?

Comment: hmmm. no i'm not sure what you mean. is there anything i can look at?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with large numbers inconsistently ending (ie. 550,000 was sometimes only counting as far as 549,826 or so).

Here's a simplified solution which toLocaleString function to add the decimal accordingly:

```js
$('.js-count').each(function() {
   
   $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      
      Counter: $(this).data('number')
   }, {
      
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
         
         $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString('en'));
      }
   });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="js-count" data-number="550000"></span>
```

I've also opted to use a data attribute to store the number. This way is a bit more bullet-proof. Relying on the content of the element can lead to miscalculating if the event fires more than once.

Comment: Logged in just to upvote this, the toLocaleString() method is far simpler and cleaner solution than using regex, which is what 95% of answers to similar questions do.